# Some records do not appear in multilist with search

Tags: content-search, content-editor

I've got a multilist with search field in Sitecore 9.2 that does not return all of the items I know it should be. The field source is `StartSearchLocation=[ID of folder]&Filter=_templatename:[template name]`. This does return a number of records, but not all.

I've confirmed the record I'm looking for is in my Sitecore indexes, and we do have custom indexes and the record is in there as well. It's not marked unpublishable or the like. My MaxItems value in settings is 0, so all records should be returned. I've seen some other answers to similar questions but the solutions I've tried from those usually make the source list disappear entirely.

Comment: Rebuilding indexes should update it

Comment: I rebuilt sitecore_master_index and even did a republish, the item still doesn't appear.

Comment: Rebuilt custom indexes too? Depending on the item location and crawling settings on custom index, Sitecore will use different indexes for multi list with search.

Comment: Can you try to see if the item is appearing if you add &fq=_indexname:sitecore_master_index at the end of your field source query? Is the item appearing if you remove the &Filter=_templatename filter?

Comment: @CristiVulturar Your suggestion was at least a "do no harm" version of one I'd seen elsewhere. Oddly the folks I was looking for finally showed up, so I wonder if unlocking them and the reindex just needed a little time to fully kick in. I'll keep that in mind if someone else is missing as a first check-step. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the Multilist Item Field Limit by updating this setting in Sitecore.config: `<setting name="Query.MaxItems" value="100" />`

Comment: As I noted, it's set to 0 now, which should be no limitation. Unless that changed and I just need to set it to a very high number?

Comment: Setting it to higher number solved the issue for me. Didn't try the 0 option.